# Navigating in View with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tv, d-pad

I have application supporting both Android TV and Smartphones

In general navigation through app goes fine, but I have one problem with layout like this

```
View with Buttons
RecyclerView
View with Buttons
```

I want navigate across this view with D-pad (or arrows) but Recycler is kinda problem.

I can set focus on recycler from upper and bottom view by setting

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/recycler"
```

and making recycler focusable, but now I want "go in" recycler for example with D-pad OK (or Enter)

**how can I move focus from recycler to first child of recycler on imeInputType (ok/enter) and reset focus on clicking (back/esc) from child back to his parent recycler?**

Comment: i think you need a programmatical approach. have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding child views programmatically, so you need to set programmatically your next focused view.

Something like this

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

            View child = mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildAt(0);
            child.setFocusable(true);
            child.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            child.requestFocus();

            // to check current focused view
            // View focused = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```